# How to find all vim mappings starting with "control key"?

Tags: vim

In vim:

- `:map` list all key mappings
- `:map {lhs}` list all key mappings for the key sequences starting with {lhs}.

How do you seach for "all key mappings starting with the control key" ?

(I know I can still list all mappings, redirect the output to a file and grep; but it is not very efficient).

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no direct, built-in, method for that.

What you can do instead is:

```
:redir @a    redirect output of next command to register a
:map         list mappings
:redir END   end redirection
:vnew        edit new buffer in vertical window
:put a       put content of register a
:v/<C-/d     delete all lines not matching '<C-'
```

Which you could turn easily into a function.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer and the work-around you provided.
And sorry for the late approval.

Comment: `:map` doesn't show native vim mappings so you still don't know whether you overwrite something or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sorted, searchable list of `:maps` output in which to search for `<C-`, you can do the following:

```
function! s:ShowMaps()
  let old_reg = getreg("a")          " save the current content of register a
  let old_reg_type = getregtype("a") " save the type of the register as well
try
  redir @a                           " redirect output to register a
  " Get the list of all key mappings silently, satisfy "Press ENTER to continue"
  silent map | call feedkeys("\<CR>")    
  redir END                          " end output redirection
  vnew                               " new buffer in vertical window
  put a                              " put content of register
  " Sort on 4th character column which is the key(s)
  %!sort -k1.4,1.4
finally                              " Execute even if exception is raised
  call setreg("a", old_reg, old_reg_type) " restore register a
endtry
endfunction
com! ShowMaps call s:ShowMaps()      " Enable :ShowMaps to call the function

nnoremap \m :ShowMaps<CR>            " Map keys to call the function
```

This is a robust function to create a vertical split with the sorted output of `:maps`. I put it in my `vimrc`.

The last line maps the two keys <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to call the function, change this as you wish.

Note: This will will not include vim's default commands like <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> to increment a number, as they are not made with `map`. See `:help index` for these.